# Replacement for CGSession --suspend?

Tags: command-line, big-sur

I used to cause my iMac to put up its lock screen from shell scripts. It was dead simple:

`'/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession' -suspend`

In MacOS Big Sur, /User.menu/ is not at that location, and I cannot find a file named CGSession. What is the equivalent command line in Big Sur? I would like to avoid using root privilege for this task.

Answer (score 2):

**User.menu** is but one of many missing on **macOS Big Sur**, namely **Battery.menu**, **Bluetooth.menu**, **Clock.menu**, **Displays.menu**, **Eject.menu**, **IrDA.menu**, **UniversalAccess.menu**, **User.menu**, and **Volume.menu**.

Assuming you have not changed the system default *keyboard shortcut* for **Lock Screen**, **⌃⌘Q**, the following *command* in **Terminal** will lock the screen:

```applescript
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to key code 12 using {control down, command down}'
```

The first time I executed that *command* it failed and I was prompted with two dialog boxes, the first being:

[image: Terminal wants access]

After clicking **OK**, the second one was:

[image: Accessibility Access (Events)]

Clicking **Open System Preferences** took me to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, where I clicked the check box for **Terminal** after unlocking the pane.

I then executed the *command* again in **Terminal** and it locked the screen.

After unlocking the screen, I then created a *shell script* as `lockscreen` in `/usr/local/bin`, e.g:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo nano lockscreen
```

Added the following *code*:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to key code 12 using {control down, command down}'
```

Then pressed **⌃X** followed by **Y** and then **Enter**, and back a the prompt:

```
sudo chmod +x lockscreen
```

I then executed the `lockscreen` *command* and it too worked, and without having to make any additional security changes. It also works when calling it from other *shell scripts*.

---

**Note:** If you prefer to use a `osascript` *shebang*, instead of `zsh`, use the following *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events" to key code 12 using {control down, command down}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there a specific reason you don't code the script with `#!/usr/bin/osascript` and then include AppleScript directly?

Comment: @nohillside,  Other than I typically only use the `#!/usr/bin/osascript` _shebang_ for longer and or more complex **AppleScript** _code_ run in a _shell script_, no, but it certainly can be done that way too. It's not unusual for there be more than one way to do something and it doesn't necessarily mean one way is better than the other.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is not equivalent in one important way: the old way used to leave the computer at the regular login screen where a list of users was shown. If you use "Lock Screen" then it appears that only the user who was already logged in can unlock the screen. Another user cannot come up and log into it. I still don't understand why Apple took away `CGSession`.

Comment: @TJ Luoma, It may not be 100% equivalent; however, testing the _command_ of the OP in **macOS Catalina** it brings up a _lock screen_ in which it shows the available **users** and has three _buttons_, **Shut Down**, **Restart** and **Sleep**. In **macOS Big Sur** the method suggested in my answer produces a _lock screen_ showing the current **user** and has a **Switch User** _button_ that if _clicked_ changes the _lock screen_ to the exact same _lock screen_ as the _command_ of the OP. So while one then needs to click an extra button to _switch users_ or perform the other actions Cont'd...

Comment: @TJ Luoma, Cont'd... available of the older _lock screen_, it is as equivalent as one can get considering the changes that **Apple** has made. The primary difference is if just a single **user** exists, then unfortunately the **user** will need to log back in in order to _restart_, _shutdown_, or _sleep_. To me, in a multiple **user** scenario, **Apple** has merrily added an extra _click_, while forcing the single **user** to log back in. Please make your feeling know at: [**macOS Feedback**](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html)

Comment: I swear I looked at that last night on Big Sur and the “Switch User” button was not there. I even looked for it, as I thought I remembered it being there… but then didn't see it. However, given that it is very clearly there today, my guess is that my eyes deceived me. Either that or there's some sort of obscure bug that I managed to trigger last night but not today. My money is on my eyes. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: @TJ Luoma, RE: "Sorry for the bother. " --  No bother and it's alway good to say something if there appear to be a discrepancy/issue. As I said, "It may not be 100% equivalent" because with a single **user** it's not and forces the single **user** to log back in, but for multiple **users** it is all we've have, click the **Switch User** _button_,  unless someone can figure some other method.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I use a workaround which doesn't exactly suspend the session but rather puts the laptop to sleep. In my workflow, these achieve the same thing as both times I get to the lock screen. Bonus part of putting the machine to sleep is it's more power efficient as I actually prefer it going to sleep when I walk away from it.

`alias lock="pmset sleepnow"` in my `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` file. Alternatively, `pmset displaysleepnow` achieves somewhat similar behaviour to what `CGSession -suspend` did.